# How "pi+1" statement does tail call elimination in quicksort function which is using the Lomuto Algorithm for partitioning?

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort, tail-recursion

> /* QuickSort after tail call elimination */

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

> A utility function to swap two elements

```
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
```

> /* This function takes last element as pivot, places
>          the pivot element at its correct position in sorted
>           array, and places all smaller (smaller than pivot)
>          to left of pivot and all greater elements to right
>          of pivot. It is using the Lomuto partition algorithm. */

```
int partition (int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[high];    `// pivot`
    int i = (low - 1);  `// Index of smaller element`

    for (int j = low; j <= high- 1; j++)
    {
        `// If the current element is smaller than or equal to pivot `
        if (arr[j] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;    `// increment index of smaller element`
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
    return (i + 1);
}
```

> /* The main function that implements QuickSort
>        arr[] --> Array to be sorted,
>         low  --> Starting index,
>         high  --> Ending index */

```
void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    while (low < high)
    {
        `/* pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now at right place */`
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);

        `// Separately sort elements before partition and after partition`
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);

        low = pi+1;
    }
}
```

> Function to print an array

```
void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

> Driver program to test above functions

```
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    quickSort(arr, 0, n-1);
    printf("Sorted array: \n");
    printArray(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: gcc -O3 can't tail call optimize this code. Are you asking why it can't? I would imagine that the answer is... because it isn't tail call recursion.

Comment: @Lundin This is a copied code from GeeksforGeeks. The statement low = pi+1 does tail call optimisation (it removes the recursive call `qsort(arr[],p+1,high)`) for better space complexity.

Comment: Oh, are you asking how the version you posted eliminated one of the two recursive calls, leaving only one?  It appears to do so by first making the recursive call on the lower portion, then setting `low` to the start of the high partition and repeating.  It can't eliminate the recursive calls entirely, but it eliminates some of them.

Comment: @SundramSharan Except it doesn't... https://godbolt.org/z/CtK_Us. That geek site deserves its poor reputation, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

> How “pi+1” statement does tail call elimination in quicksort function

It doesn't. All the mainstream x86 compilers fail to unroll the recursion from your code. For example gcc -O3 ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/CtK_Us)):

```
quickSort:
        cmp     esi, edx
        jge     .L6
        push    r13
        mov     r13, rdi
        push    r12
        mov     r12d, edx
        push    rbp
        mov     ebp, esi
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 8
.L3:
        mov     esi, ebp
        mov     edx, r12d
        mov     rdi, r13
        call    partition
        mov     esi, ebp
        mov     rdi, r13
        mov     ebx, eax
        lea     edx, [rax-1]
        call    quickSort     // recursive call
        lea     ebp, [rbx+1]
        cmp     r12d, ebp
        jg      .L3
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        pop     r12
        pop     r13
        ret
```